# Ways of Assigning Grades to Students

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was reading somewhere that the number of ways 10 students could be assigned the grades A,B,C,F would be $4^{10}$. However, that seems to be counting sequences such as AABCFBFAFC and switching the second A with the first A as two different sequences. So am I correct that $4^{10}$ is not the correct number of possible sequences? If, how would one then account for repetition when the number of elements repeated is varying? I know in general for $n$ repetitions of element x, the possibilities are, let N be the total elements->$N!/n!$. However, n is varying in the case I stated above for each element.

Thank you

Comment: $4^{10}$ is correct.  Put the students in alphabetical order.  Assign a grade to each student in order. There are $4$ choices for each student.

Comment: @paw88789 So $4^{10}$ does not count flipping the two front $A's$ as two different sequences, i.e. overcounting?

Comment: No.  That sequence is only counted once.  Look at the example of two students in alphabetical order: AA, AB, AC, AF, BA, BB, BC, BF, CA, CB, CC, CF, FA, FB, FC, FF.  The AA sequence, for instance, is not overcounted.

Comment: dylan7: Here we do not have to consider the order of the 10 students. Just need their grade combinations for a one particular order as paw88789 did

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you. So when does one need to divide by the number of ways the repetitions can be ordered from the total possibilities, as I stated above? Does this only happen when factorial is used for the total possibilities?